# 301 Redirects with "/" and no "/" - Can these be combined?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

New to 301 rules and I'm trying to find out if it's possible to combine URLs with and without "/" at the end.

Here's an example of my htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#Redirects
Redirect 301 /old/old-url/ https://www.newdomain.com/newurl/
Redirect 301 /old/old-url  https://www.newdomain.com/newurl/
```

Is there a way to combine these two redirects into one ? or will every 301 need to be written with both "/" and no "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can combine it but don't use `Redirect` with other `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirects
RewriteRule ^old/old-url(/.*)?$ https://www.newdomain.com/newurl/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

`(/.*)?` in the end will match optional trailing slash.

Comment: I wasn't able to get that RewriteRule to work until I added (/?.*) for the trailing slash, instead of />$   - any reason that might cause a problem ?

Comment: That means you URL also has other components after `/old/old-url/`. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, you've been a huge help!